# Finding Future Investment Value in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and have a question regarding the calculation of future investment values based on the following formula : 
futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)numberOfMonths
... ofc the numberOfMonths value is an exponent.
I have created this so far but seem to receive incorrect answers when running the program

```
#Question 2

investmentAmount = float(input("Enter investment amount: "))

annualInterestRate = float(input("Enter annual interest rate: "))

monthlyInterestRate = ((annualInterestRate)/10)/12

numberOfYears = eval(input("Enter number of years: "))

numberOfMonths = numberOfYears * 12

futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) **\
                     numberOfMonths
print("Accumulated value is", futureInvestmentValue)
```

what do I need to fix in order to get this thing to work, any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: "seem to receive incorrect answers"? Maybe you should come back when you are sure, and can explain just what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`annualInterestRate` should be divided by 12 to get `monthlyInterestRate`.

The correct final formula should be

```
futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + (monthlyInterestRate/100) ** \
                        numberOfMonths
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from __future__ import division # assuming python 2.7.xxxxx

investmentAmount = float(input("Enter investment amount: "))

annualInterestRate = float(input("Enter annual interest rate: "))

monthlyInterestRate = ((annualInterestRate)/10)/12

try:
   numberOfYears = int(input("Enter number of years: "))
except Exception, R:
   print "Year must be a number"

numberOfMonths = numberOfYears * 12

futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) **\
                 numberOfMonths
print("Accumulated value is", futureInvestmentValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are in:

```
monthlyInterestRate = ((annualInterestRate)/10)/12
futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) **\
                     numberOfMonths
```

There are two errors i think. The first is that the interest rate is being divided by 10 when it should be divided by 100. Right now, if you enter 2, its treated as 20% interest because `2/10` = `.2`.

The second error is that `monthlyInterestRate` assumes a flat interest rate whereas `futureInvestmentValue` assumes a compound interest rate. It should be 
`monthlyInterestRate = (1 + (annualInterestRate/100))**(.1/1.2)`.

For example(Using /12):

```
print 0.05/12
print (1+0.05/12)**12
```

Output:

```
0.00416666666667
1.05116189788
```

The monthly interest rate compounded is not equal to the annual interest rate  for a single year. Its because in one case you divide by 12, the next case you raise to the raise to the power of 12 which are not equivalent.

Example (Using **1/12)

```
from __future__ import division
print (1.05**(1/12))**12 #returns 1.05
```

Comment: I really cannot believe I missed such a simple error, thank you very much Yarnspinner. As I said, I am a beginner programmer and have not familiarized myself with the process of debugging my code whether it be a logic or syntax error.

Comment: No problem! Please mark the question as answered if you've solved it! You should print the intermediate steps if you're getting unexpected results, usually that will help alot in finding the error

Answer (score 0):

```
investmentAmount = eval(input("Enter investment amount: "))
annualInterestRate = eval(input("Enter annual interest rate: "))
monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate) / 10 / 12
numberOfYears = eval(input("Enter number of years: "))
numberOfMonths = numberOfYears * 12

futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) **\
                 numberOfMonths
print("Accumulated value is", futureInvestmentValue)
```

**You just have one mistake which is "eval"**